# Move from an adapter to a fragment in kotlin

Tags: android-recyclerview, adapter, android-navigation, android-navigation-graph

i am programming an android app in kotlin and i want to move from an adapter to a fragment after a click . But  i can't use navigation there because of the action required ( i am used to use navigation between fragments not between an adapter and a fragment ) . How to do it ?